# Fixing Excel Number formatting after Access export to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

"The Number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"

I have about 300 lines with two columns of numbers and each one says this error. It does not allow me to format the cells as numbers (doesn't stick). It does allow me to change it when that error comes up but only within that error menu.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I am working witha template file to be used for an export using the access code:

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                              TableName, ExcelPath, True
```

Comment: Is the data in your table set to number?

Comment: yes, but it has null entries.

Comment: That shouldn't matter as far as I'm concerned. When using the transferspreadsheet to a new excel file instead of the template, does it throw back the same error in excel? You can also try the `Trim()` function on the data in excel to perhaps get rid of any trailing nulls.

Comment: I figured out the why, Some of the queries have empty strings filling those columns. I switched to Null instead of "" and then it didnt work (blank numbers and weird symbols)

Comment: Yes it does produce the same error, I think the fomatting of the cell is changed to match the export field which I just realized is a string because of the empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up addint this to my code to take care of it. It takes about 6 seconds but it is in a once a month automation which is saving the user hours so I think it is acceptable.

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, WorkSheet As Excel.WorkSheet
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NewFileName)
Set WorkSheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
'begin workbook formatting
For Each cell In WorkSheet.Range("G2:H500")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value * 1
    End If
Next cell
```

The check for empty strings leaves the empty strings as that, without it they become 0